# Where to keep nuget packages for .fsi scripts? (F#)

Tags: f#, fsi

I know that I can use `#r <pkg>` but without a directory to hold a project where should I install /keep the dependencies?

I mean, if I'm using F# I can `dotnet add package <pkg>` from the project folder but with .fsx I was expecting to not have a "project folder", how to install packages then?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to worry about downloading and storing the packages somewhere, you can make the interpreter take care of that for you by [referencing Nuget packages](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-f-5/#package-references-in-f-scripts), not files on your local system. This would look something like this:

```ml
#r "nuget: <pkg>"

open Package.Whatever

...
```

Comment: Just a note that this was introduced in F# 5, so it might not be available to everyone yet.

Comment: It will download the packages for me?

Comment: Yes, it will. Check out the description I linked.